# Error with Firebase updateUser Atomicity and onAuthStateChanged useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I am having a synchrony error with user creation in firebase. Essentially, when a new user is created the following function is called in my sign up component:

```
const handleSignUp = async () => {
  // Create the user with email and password
  const userCredential = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

  await userCredential.user.updateProfile({
      displayName: name,
  });

  // User is signed up with the name added to their profile and Firestore document.
  // You can handle redirection or any other logic here.
}
```

Then, in my app.js, I have a `useEffect` listening for a change in the auth state. When, a user signs in, it should call `syncUser` which creates a document in my Firestore database for that user. However, it seems like these `useEffect` is being called before the `updateProfile` is called in the sign in. Thus, when it is called, `user.displayName` is `null`.

```
useEffect(() => {
const unregisterAuthObserver = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {

  if (user) {
    if(user.displayName) // A: Sometimes this is null in the beginning
    {
      await syncUsers(user); // B
    }
    setCurrentUser(user);


  } else {
    setCurrentUser(null);

  }

});
return () => unregisterAuthObserver();
```

I've tried a couple of different solutions. One is as you see above to check if `user.displayName` is not null before calling `syncUsers`. However, the effect of this is just to prevent the document from being created at all, as the `useEffect` is only called once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `useEffect` handler calls `onAuthStateChanged`, which triggers when the user's authentication state changes. The auth state changes when the user signs in, so when you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. However updating the current user's profile requires that they're already signed in, so the call to `updateProfile` does not cause the authentication **state** to change.

You'll need to use another/additional mechanism to trigger your code, for example calling `syncUsers` after your call to `updateProfile` completes.

You can also [listen for `onIdTokenChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth.md#authonidtokenchanged), which is called whenever the user's profile changes in the client. This may take up to an hour as the ID token doesn't auto-refresh for remote changes to the user profile, but it's worth testing what it does in your case.

Comment: Would it work to just put `syncUser(userCredential.user)` in the sign up page and remove it from app.js entirely?

Comment: If that works for your use-case, it sounds fine too. 